# Showing/Hiding Panels based on button

Tags: c#

I've seen a few answers on this already but it doesn't seem like any of them work for some reason so figured I'd pass my code along here and see if somebody is noticing something that I'm missing. I have created my form to work kind of like a custom tabbed form where when the user presses a button from my side panel the appropriate panel is displayed in the main section. Here is a simplified version of my code:

```cs
// From the function that is fired on each button click
// Set active button
currentBtn = (IconButton)senderBtn;
currentBtn.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(52, 73, 94);
currentBtn.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(142, 68, 173);
currentBtn.IconColor = Color.FromArgb(142, 68, 173);
currentBtn.Font = new Font(currentBtn.Font, FontStyle.Bold);

// Left panel to show active
leftBorderBtn.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(142, 68, 173);
leftBorderBtn.Location = new Point(0, currentBtn.Location.Y);
leftBorderBtn.Visible = true;
leftBorderBtn.BringToFront();

// Show panel
switch (currentBtn.Text)
{
    case "Lobby":
        HideForms();
        lobbyPanel.Visible = true;
        break;
    case "User":
        HideForms();
        hostPanel.Visible = true;
        break;
}

// This is my HideForms function (again a basic version)
private void HideForms()
{
    lobbyPanel.Visible = false;
    hostPanel.Visible = false;
}
```

From my understanding what *should* be happening here is: after pressing my button it should hide all the panels and then only set the panel I want to visible. However, my hostPanel works fine but the lobbyPanel doesn't for whatever reason. Any help on why this isn't working would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: When you step through your code in a debugger, what specifically happens in the non-working scenario?  Is that `case` block entered at all?  How specifically does this "not work"?

Comment: Hi @David the block is entered correctly. While stepping through it with the debugger it shows that it goes into HideForms() and hides all the forms before returning back and setting the correct form to visible. The issue is that my form doesn't actually show.

Comment: You can simplify the code: `lobbyPanel.Visible = currentBtn.Text == "Lobby"; hostPanel.Visible = currentBtn.Text == "User";`. This makes one button visible and all the others hidden. Is it possible that a panel is hidden behind another one?

Comment: I think you need to show more code. Please show the full methods so we can see exactly what currentbutton, iconbutton, senderbutton, and leftborderbtn are. Are those actually buttons or panels?

Comment: Does this "simplified" code work as expected??

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I've tried keeping them all visible and just using `BringToFront()` to move the one I need to the front with no success unfortunately.

Comment: @David.Warwick all of those work correctly and its not really related to that, I just included that to show where I'm making the call from.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield unfortunately it does not. The host panel shows when the User button is clicked no problem. However, the lobby panel never shows no matter what I do.

Comment: No enough details to tell. 1) comment `leftBorderBtn.BringToFront();` and try. 2) Check the size and position of that lobby panel when you show it. You could `DockStyle.Fill` the panels. 3) Check the `Click` event of the lobby button.

Comment: @dr.null leftBorderBtn is just a code side only panel that adds to the left side of the active button. I tried commenting out like you suggested to see if that would make a difference and unfortunately it didn't. I also tried `DockStyle.Fill` on my lobbyPanel after making it visible (I also tried manually setting the location using `lobbyPanel.Location = new Point(200, 50);`) with no success. The odd part to me is that the hostPanel works flawlessly when the user button is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a better approach that works flawlessly and was actually rather easy to implement. Thanks to [RJ Code Advance EN](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCrOMiLLn857KqOzZYIqO-hQ) on YouTube I found this.

The solution was to separate the panels into new Forms and then create a method to invoke these forms:

```cs
// Track our current form
private Form currentForm = null;

// Our method
private void openForm(Form childForm)
{
    // If form is not null close current form
    if (currentForm != null)
    {
        currentForm.Close();
    }

    // Set current form to passed in form and set it up to show
    currentForm = childForm;
    childForm.TopLevel = false;
    childForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

    // Grab the empty panel for displaying our form
    childPanelForm.Controls.Add(childForm);
    childPanelForm.Tag = childForm;

    // Show our form
    childForm.BringToFront();
    childForm.Show();
}
```

In my case I created an panel in my main form called `childPanelForm` that's sole purpose was to be used to display any child Forms as you can see above. Then, whenever you want to invoke your method you would do this (in my example on button click):

```cs
// Set active button
currentBtn = (IconButton)senderBtn;
currentBtn.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(52, 73, 94);
currentBtn.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(142, 68, 173);
currentBtn.IconColor = Color.FromArgb(142, 68, 173);
currentBtn.Font = new Font(currentBtn.Font, FontStyle.Bold);

// Left panel to show active
leftBorderBtn.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(142, 68, 173);
leftBorderBtn.Location = new Point(0, currentBtn.Location.Y);
leftBorderBtn.Visible = true;
leftBorderBtn.BringToFront();

// Show panel
switch (currentBtn.Text)
{
    case "Lobby":
        openChildForm(new LobbyForm());
        break;
    case "User":
        openChildForm(new HostForm());
        break;
}
```